# Reading Years Out of Monthly Dates in SAS

Tags: sas

I have a monthly time series datain which the format of the dates are the last day of each month, for example 31jan2003. I like to creat another variable "year" that only shows the year of each observation, so for all 12 months in 2003 it would be equal to 2003 and for all 12 months in 2004 it would be 2004 and so on.
I was wondering if there is a function or procedure in SAS for this purpose?

Thanks,
SE

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The function is `year`, strangely enough.

```
year('31jan2003'd) /* 2003 */
```